# Yii add code to HTML headers

Tags: php, templates, yii

I am using the Yii Framework, Let's say all my pages use the same layout templates. Once in a while, for some specific controller/actions I want my HTML  to have some extra code (extra css, javascript, meta ...).

What's the conventional way to achieve this? Creating a new layout seems overkill.

In GRAILS you can just write the extra html you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Register Meta Tag](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript/#registerMetaTag-detail)

[Register Script File](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail) / [Script](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScript-detail)

[Register CSS File](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCssFile-detail) / [CSS](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCss-detail)

Comment: Where would a `<link rel="canonical"` fall?

Comment: @NathanH  
  
use [RegisterLinkTag](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript/#registerLinkTag-detail)  
  
Example: `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerLinkTag("canonical",NULL,"http://google.com/")`